# Adding new contact with photo via ContactsContract and ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, contactscontract

I've been trying all day to add contact with photo to Android Contacts. Finally I'm adding picture to contact, but I can't add any name or phone number. Contact is displaying as "(Unknown)", with proper photo.

My code:

```
private void addContact2() {
final String displayName = "XYZA";
final String mobileNumber = "666666";
final byte[] photoByteArray; // initalized elsewhere

ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "")
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "")
        .build());

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName)
        //.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, displayName)
        .build());

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, photoByteArray)
        .build());

Uri newContactUri = null;
ContentProviderResult[] res = null;
try {
    final ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    res = contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    if (res != null && res.length > 0 && res[0] != null) {
        newContactUri = res[0].uri;
        Log.d(CallActivity.class.getName(), "URI added contact:"+ newContactUri);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully added " + displayName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else Log.e(CallActivity.class.getName(), "Contact not added.");
} catch (NullPointerException | RemoteException | OperationApplicationException e) {
    Log.e(CallActivity.class.getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've fixed it. On "name" ops.add I wrote `.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)` instead of `.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)`. Now everything works fine.