# getting ANR creating contact through my app when any contact app is not installed

Tags: android

I am creating contact through my app.But if any contact app in not in the phone then its giving ANR. How can I check if any contact app is installed or not in phone.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, contactNumber)
      .putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, contactName);
```

Comment: Why don't you use content provider to create contact? It won't require contact app installation

Comment: can you provide any code snippet - @Sagar

Answer (score 0):

catch block is called when no app installed to resolve your intent, you can notify the user on the block

```
try {
  startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
  //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Intent` you can use ContentProvider to create a contact. This won't require need of having Contact's app on your device. You can follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579129/adding-new-contact-with-photo-via-contactscontract-and-contentprovider) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

- ANR dialog come because you perform  operation take more than 5
  second  in main thread.So you should be do in background thread.
- You should be try this.
- method of contactpicker :

Example :

```
public void contactIntent(View v){

            Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // check whether the result is ok
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Check for the request code, we might be usign multiple startActivityForReslut
            switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_PICK_CONTACT:
                contactPicked(data);
                break;
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Failed to pick contact");
        }
    }
    /**
     * Query the Uri and read contact details. Handle the picked contact data.
     * @param data
     */
    private void contactPicked(Intent data) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String phoneNo = null ;
            String name = null;
            // getData() method will have the Content Uri of the selected contact
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            //Query the content uri
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            // column index of the phone number
            int  phoneIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            // column index of the contact name
            int  nameIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
            phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
            name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
            // Set the value to the textviews
            textView1.setText(name);
            textView2.setText(phoneNo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```